# How to decode html-input to int in Elm?

Tags: parsing, input, decode, elm

There's html-input. We listen input-events and update model(which is simple string here). Now I'd like to use Int type for model, and to parse Int from input's value. I made another decoder and changed initial model's value to 0. After those changes model doesn't changes when I type digits. Why? How to implement it?

```
import Html exposing (input, div, text)
import Html.Events
import StartApp.Simple
import Json.Decode

model = ""

view address model =
  let

    decoder =
      Html.Events.targetValue

    -- this decoder doesn't work
    decoderInt =
      Json.Decode.at ["target", "value"] Json.Decode.int

  in
    div [] [
      input [ Html.Events.on "input" decoder (Signal.message address) ] [],
      text (toString model)
    ]

update action model =
  action

main =
  StartApp.Simple.start { model = model, view = view, update = update }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Json decoding isn't working because the Json value is a string, even though the value inside the string is a number. For instance, the Json value looks something like this:

```json
{ "target": { "value": "42" } }
```

Elm's Json Decoding functions are very strict, so they're going to see `"42"` as merely a string. You'll need to go one step further to build up a decoder that parses the inside of that string as a number - an act which could fail if the user types something non-numeric.

For this we can switch back to using the `Html.Events.targetValue` decoder initially, since it knows how to decode the string value. We then pass that through `Json.Decode.andThen` to pull out the value of that string and act upon on.

```elm
decoderInt =
  Html.Events.targetValue `Json.Decode.andThen` \str ->
    case String.toInt str of
      Ok i ->
        Json.Decode.succeed i
      Err msg ->
        Json.Decode.fail msg
```

The use of `succeed` and `fail` are there to map the value back into the type of `Decoder Int`.